# Binding to ListView Xamarin Froms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind an Observable Collection of objects to a list view.
I have put a debug in the view model and it shows that the collection is there. But it doesn't seem to be be showing on the front end.

This is the Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>      



    <ListView
              x:Name="dataList"                    
              ItemsSource="{Binding routeLabels}" >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding RouteName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class DriverDashboardView : ContentPage
{
    private DriverDashboardViewModel driverdashboardviewmodel;


    public DriverDashboardView()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = "Driver's Dashboard";
        BindingContext = driverdashboardviewmodel = new DriverDashboardViewModel();

    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await driverdashboardviewmodel.GetLabelInfo();
    }   

}
```

and the view model:

```
public class DriverDashboardViewModel:BaseViewModel,INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    public DriverDashboardViewModel()
    {


    }

    public async Task GetLabelInfo()
    {
        _routelabels = await service.return_label_info();

    }

    // property change handler to bind to UI
    private ObservableCollection<RouteInfo> _routelabels;
    public ObservableCollection<RouteInfo> routeLabels
    {
        get { return _routelabels; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _routelabels)) return;
            _routelabels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(routeLabels));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the RouteInfo class:

```
public class RouteInfo
{
    public string RouteName { get; set; }
    public int Stops { get; set; }
    public string DayOf { get; set; }

}
```

As I stated I put a debug in the view model and I can see the data is there.
But I cant see it on the front end.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you remove your `ItemTemplate` do you see the correct number of entries in your front-end? If so, then it is a problem with your template. If not, then it sounds like a problem with your binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `DriverDashboardViewModel.GetLabelInfo()` method you are assigning the results to `_routelabels`. But `_routelabels` does not ever call `OnPropertyChanged()` which is required for the change to tell the UI to reevaluate it's binding.

I would suggest assigning the results of `await service.return_label_info();` directly to `routeLabels` instead.

But you could also keep the `GetLabelInfo()` code the way it is now and just add the following after the `_routelabels` assignment to manually tigger a UI update: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(routeLabels));`

So in summary do one of these 2 things:

```
public async Task GetLabelInfo() {
    routeLabels = await service.return_label_info();
}
```

Or:

```
public async Task GetLabelInfo() {
    _routelabels = await service.return_label_info();
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(routeLabels));
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!
I will accept this when it lets me.